# Angulartics doesn't track my events on buttons or links

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-analytics, angulartics

I've followed the "tutorial" on Angulartics' website and ended up with this event code on my buttons and links:

**Buttons**

```
<button class="btn btn-default" ng-controller="ctrl" ng-click="openModal()" analytics-on="click" analytics-event="button" analytics-categori="Main page" analytics-label="Modal bottom">Open modal!</button>
```

**Links**

```
<a ui-sref="ui.state" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" analytics-on="click" analytics-event="button" analytics-categori="Header" analytics-label="FAQ">FAQ</a>
```

I have injected both *angulartics* and *angulartics.google.analytics* to my app and it works as it should, no errors anywhere. I have deleted the *ga('send', 'pageview')* from the Google Analytics code-snippet.

The event tracking works if I put it in my controller with this snippet:

```
$analytics.eventTrack('event', {category: 'category', label: 'label'});
```

Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong when adding the code to my links and buttons?

EDIT

I've tried to remove analytics-on="click" and instead just have analytics-on but that doesn't work either.

```
<button ng-click="openModal()" analytics-on analytics-event="button" analytics-categori="Main page" analytics-label="Modal bottom">Open modal!</button>
```

Comment: I wouldn't put ng-controller on the same element you attach an ng-click to... that seems like a bad idea to me I would wrap your button in a node and attach ng-controller to that.

Comment: Yeah, that was a bad example.. But I will definitively look into it =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured out what the problem was, I had misspelled "category" in "analytics-category" and therefor Angulartics didn't register any events.

Thanks to btm1 though for getting my thoughts going on other solutions =)

Answer (score 0):

to answer your question ng-click takes the click handler for that element the same goes for analytics-on="click" the two don't work nicely together because you've got two events conflicting with one another.

The best thing to do would be to create a function in your controller that gets fired via ng-click and then put your google analytics code inside of that function.

Comment: But why doesn't it work on the links? Is it because UI Router transforms ui-sref to a click-event that is fired before analytics-on?

Comment: because ui sref might use mousedown or mouseup or a custom click event all together.